# Get base_url from main domain and sub domain in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have two application for my project

1. site.com
2. api.site.com

And here's my config

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
```

---

If I run **site.com**, how to get base_url or site_url of **api.site.com**?

If I run **api.site.com**, how to get base_url or site_url of **site.com**?

Comment: If you have only two application. And If your $config['base_url'] is giving 'http://site.com' then use another one else another one.;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no such function to retrieve the URL in your way. You need to do it manually. Create a helper called `base_helper.php` inside `helpers` directory and write this code.

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

if (!function_exists('url')) {

    function url($param = TRUE)
    {
        if ($param) {
            return 'http://site.com/';
        }
        return 'http://api.site.com/';
    }

}
```

You can call this helpers in controllers/views you wish. Use `true` and `false` parameter to get main domain or sub domain.

```
$this->load->helper('base');
echo url();
echo "\n";
echo url(false);
```

Prints

```
http://site.com/
http://api.site.com/
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If you use following code for base_url then you don't need to change anything you can use this in any server as well as any domain subdomain IP address

```
$config['base_url'] = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https://" : "http://") . 
  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . preg_replace('@/+$@', '', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) . '/';
```

Comment: Thanks for the code man. I have tried an existing code from 2013 and it dint work for me (yours did): $config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_POST'];
$config['base_url'] .= preg_replace('@/+$@',' ',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])).'/';

Answer (score 0):

I hope site.com and api.site.com will have different content. It is best to have two application folders and two different index.php file in each root directory. You can share the same system files, by updating the system path in the index.php file.